# Django - Access ForigenKey object fields of chain in a template

Tags: python, django, templates

Assuming the following cenario at a django app:

views.py:

```
def my_purchases(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        list_my_purchases = sorted(
            chain(
                Item_X_Licence.objects.filter(user=request.user, status=1),
                Item_Y_Licence.objects.filter(user=request.user, status=1)
            ), key=attrgetter('paid_date'), reverse=True
        )
        paginator = Paginator(list_my_purchases, 20)  # Show 20 per page
        page = request.GET.get('page')
        my_purchases = paginator.get_page(page)
        user = request.user
        args = {'user': user,
                'my_purchases': my_purchases,
                }
        return render(request, 'App/my_purchases.html', args)
```

and the following 2 models (Item_X and Item_Y are basically the same, so I will only show it for one of them here)

models.py

```
class Item_X_Licence(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item_X, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=PAYMENT_STATUS, default=0)
    paid_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

...

```
class Item_X(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=25)
```

....

My question now is the following:

How can I access the title of Item_X in my_purchases.html template?
currently I'm only able to get back the Item_X_Licence object (id) itself, but thats basically everything ...

```
{% for my_purchases in my_purchases %}
   <tr class="font-size-small">
       <td>{{ my_purchases }}</td>
   </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Currently list_my_purchases acceses Item_X_Licence but I dont know how i can get up to Item_X and the fields like author and title as i want to display them at my template.

thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to access the Item_x in the template in  you can do something like this in the loop

```
{{list_my_purchases.item.title}}
```

In general, Django prefetched all the related objects, so you can access the data with just using '.' notation and going to the right attribute.